# How to read all subfolder and files of a tar file(given the file name in command line arg) in python

Tags: python

I want to read the the all subfolder and files by givingh the file name in command line argument. Then I want to untar the file. I have given the part of this code.But it throw error.How would I resolve this.

```
root = "/tempo"
path = os.path.join(root, "alu_it")

def untar(dir1):
    tar = tarfile.open(dir1)
    f=tar.extractall('untar')
    print "untar --->", f
    return

for name in f:
    print "Filename : %s" % name
    decode(name);
    tar.close()

# Test for Subdirs
def subDirTest():
    for dir1 in sys.argv[1:]:
        # untar(dir1);
        for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
            for filename in files:
                print os.path.join(path,filename)
untar(dir);
subDirTest();
```

Comment: Please post your entire code, it looks like your `import tarfile ` is missing...

Comment: no I have imported the tar file..the error is.             Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kpeg2carbon.py", line 78, in <module>
    untar(dir);
  File "kpeg2carbon.py", line 62, in untar
    tar = tarfile.open(dir1)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/tarfile.py", line 1652, in open
    return func(name, "r", fileobj, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/tarfile.py", line 1714, in gzopen
    fileobj = bltn_open(name, mode + "b")
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, builtin_function_or_method found

Comment: Please update your question instead of putting this stack trace into a comment....